# Battery life severely decreased after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: dell, 16.04, battery

Recently I upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, and my laptop's battery life has drastically decreased. When I used 14.04 my battery life was roughly 3.5 hours, now it's only about 2 hours.

I tried to calibrate it with `powertop`, and I added suggested rules to `rc.local` but it didn't help. I also disabled zeitgeist, because it was probably guilty of heavy disk I/O. My laptop is a Dell 3543, can anyone suggest me what else can I do?